# Reading temperature of CPU crashing eventually

Tags: temperature

I am running the newest version `Linux raspberrypi 4.1.10-v7+ #820 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 4 16:26:51 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux` on an RPi 2,

And when I read the temperature pf the CPU though any method my system eventually completely crashes.

I've tried `cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` and `vcgencmd measure_temp` and I even tried a python script like this:

```python
f=open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp")
while True:
    f.seek(0)
    temp=f.read()
    #do something
```

but they all eventually crash my RPi so bad that all of the lights (ACT and PWR) and my wifi card LED just stay on, no flashing nothing. After that I can just unplug it, plug it back in, and be good to go.

Is there any fix for this? A way to prevent it?

Comment: Do you have Jessie or Wheezy?

Comment: Hmmm.... never heard of anything like this. Just curious, do you have the luxury to download NOOBS again (or just raspbian) and install it on the Pi again? If not, just try: Sudo apt-get update Sudo apt-get upgrade Then try it again. My reasoning was you just ran into a bug. If you're using Jessie, well Raspbian Jessie is relatively new. You can report the bug [here](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs).

Comment: @Shojan I am using Wheezy, and I just updated yesterday. Also this is a very common bug.

Comment: Are you consuming a resource you are not releasing in do something?

Comment: @joan Nope, just print.

Comment: @PatrickCook is there a time.sleep(0.001) or similar in do something?  I'm not sure how or whenPython garbage collects the old temp variables.

Comment: @joan yep, a sleep(5)

Comment: Are you using some kind of GPIO pin?
Because this situation i faced when i am not give good power supply ie. 5v and due to which it crash and i need to re plug all again.

Comment: I am using an LCD screen attached to 5v, but I have a 2A power supply and another 3A powered USB hub attached, there is no way I am using more than 5A

Comment: When you say "completely crashes"  does that mean a kernel panic?  Do you get a stack trace on the console?  If so, post it here and someone can give a better answer...

Comment: @Brian, nothing, it just fails, no trace of anything suspicious in any of the logs.

Comment: Have you tried opening and closing the memory file every time the loop runs?

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yah, I read up on it and its just a problem with Debian Linux.

Comment: Mind putting in an explanation as a self answered question then? It would help people who may have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly three years later, I'm answering this question even though I answered it in the comments and this is a dead operating system:

According to [a discussion on the raspberry pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=28361), this is simply a problem with the OS. Since the system itself reads the temperature every so often for various purposes, it becomes increasingly likely with time that my script and the system will try to access the temperature file at the same time, causing it to hang.

So, in short, not a fixable issue.